# I have a image that is over the popup window, I want it to be under it

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a image that get displayed over the window that pops up, it shouldnt do that. The image should be underneath the window popup.

I guess I need to do something in the css?

here is the css for the image:

```
.ribbon{
    background:url(../images/ribbon.png) no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    width:152px;
    height:132px;
    z-index:999999999;
    margin:-4px 0 0 -4px;
}
```

Comment: It would really help to post all the relevant markup and css here. But an educated guess would be to set the z-index property to be lower than that of the window that pops up over it.

Comment: I checked the jquery on the window that pops ups and the z-index was lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove or change that extremely huge `z-index`, which probably is greater than the *popup*'s `z-index`!

Answer (score 1):

You should set the CSS "z-index:9999999;" property on the image to something lower than the z-index of the window that's popping up.

See if changing that to z-index:1; fixes it perhaps.

Not having the window css as well though I can't tell what number it would be to make the image appear behind the popup.

Answer (score 1):

I think your z-index is too high. Try to set it lower than that.